# How to call Screen flow from record triggered flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I want to call screen flow from record triggered flow and same screen flow on click of button.

Answer (score 3):

As of now there is no way to call Screen flow from a record triggered flow.

Because screen flow requires user interaction and record triggered flow gets automatically executed once the record has any change.

**NOTE** : There are workaround to trigger the screen flow, if you can subscribe to a platform event on Lightning page, but that comes with its own limitations and issues.

Comment: I doubt there will ever be a direct way to do it. Remember that a record triggered flow responds to any CRUD operation against relevant records, regardless as to how that happens. This could be due to a scheduled job, a REST API call or some asynchronous processing inserting or updating relevant records. In each case, there is no UI context, so nowhere to present the screens.

Answer (score 1):

The unofficial extension Detect and Launch will launch Screen Flows based on a record change created from a record-triggered flow: https://unofficialsf.com/from-andy-haas-trigger-screen-flows-with-record-changes-using-detect-and-launch/